# Multiplayer Game Networking Architecture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer, photon

I've been learning how to do networking between a Unity Client and a Photon Server. Here is what I'm currently doing.

Unity Client runs a frame every 16ms or a total of 60 frames per second, once connected the frame # starts at 0 and increments by 1 at the very end (LateUpdate), the Photon ServerPeer will also have a joined on frame # variable that holds what frame on the server they joined.
Photon server runs a PoolFiber interval of 16ms, Server increments every poolfiber interval by 1 to get the frame #
On the client, In the LateUpdate method, at the very end of the frame, it will send a Request to get the next frame data from the server.
The server will receive the request and en-queue it for the next frame, grab the next several frames (what is available) and sends it out to the client. Client takes that data and will execute it on it's proper frame. Repeating the process of requesting at end of the frame and processing at the beginning.
First off, is this a good way of doing it? I'm just starting out learning networking and I'd really love to understand this better, after some research this seemed like a good method of sync'ing the client/server.

My problem with this approach though is the client frame rate is ALWAYS surpassing the server frame rate so much so that the client just keeps getting further and further out of reach of the server.

For instance, the client will start at 0 while the server is at 1,200, eventually the client will be 2,200 and the server will only be 1,900. I've noticed that anywhere between 1-3 client frames are being processed in 1 frame on the server.

So: Client Frame 1, 2, 3 all being processed on server frame 1200.

What is a good way of tackling this? I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out for weeks.

Comment: Depending on display settings, frames could be rendered at anything from 30Hz to 240Hz and beyond. So no matter what, depending on this frame rate being 60Hz is a bad idea. It sounds like you're trying to implement lockstep networking, so [here's one article that describes a way to do that in Unity](http://clintonbrennan.com/2013/12/lockstep-implementation-in-unity3d/). I think you should focus on reading rather than trying to figure it out yourself; there are a *lot* of resources and things aren't always intuitive.

Comment: Short version: synchronizing two or more computers _must_ be done using a common reference. You cannot hope that separate processing on each computer will somehow just work out to have the same timing. The most obvious "common reference" is a clock. You can also get away with having a single computer's processing determine the timing for all other computers involved. In any case, the general problem is very broad; there are many different approaches and solutions, and you'll need to narrow the question significantly before it is suitable for Stack Overflow.